# mustache не видит русский язык

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, mustache

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой подключения mustache в html файл.
[image: index.mustache]

Создаю spring-boot проект.
В итоге выводит код вот так на странице:
[image: вывод mustache файла]

Без понятия, как это фиксить в базу данных соответственно тоже заносятся кракозябры
[image: pgAdmin 4]

**При всем при этом, простой файл html выводит русский нормально:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Вывод простого html файла]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вместо русских символов на сайте выводятся непонятные символы. Очевидно проблема с кодировкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, спустя 6 часов, я нашел не одно решение проблемы - а несколько, и оба методом проб и ошибок)))
Алгоритм их работы могу описать лишь на уровне пониманию ( хотя я до сих пор немного в ауте почему работает так и никак иначе)
Вариант 1:

1. У вас слишком новая версия Spring Boot. Заменить его до предыдущей доступной.

Пример:
в файле pom.xml

```
 <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            **<version>2.7.2</version>**
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
```

Я изменил на:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        **<version>2.4.3</version>**
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Все заработало. Кириллицу стал распознавать.

Вариант 2:
Опять какая-то хе*ня с Maven.
Поменял в настройках IDEA с Maven Bundled ( версии Maven 3.8.1 ) на скаченный из инета версии Maven 3.8.6.

По итогу в pom.xml даже менять ничего не надо, оставил свой Spring Boot 2.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Так лучше:

```
spring.mustache.charset=utf-8
```